# Adding routes dynamically and creating new files as per route

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.3

I'm developing a master layout. There should be provision of adding menus and submenus dynamically from admin panel. I have stored the menus and submenus name in database. I have assigned the routes for known menus statically in routes file.

How do I assign routes to new menus created dynamically from admin panel? Furthermore, how do I dynamically create files (view files) so that the routes point to that file.

Basically until now I've done followings:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex')->name('index');
Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@getContact')->name('contact');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@getAbout')->name('about');
Route::get('/download', 'PagesController@getDownload')->name('download');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::resource('menus', 'MenuController');
Route::resource('submenus', 'SubmenuController');
```

[Table for menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0qhf.png)

[Table for submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF6im.png)

```
public function index()
{
    $menus = Menu::all();
    return view('menus.index')->withMenus($menus);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('menus.create');
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'menu_name' => "required|min:3|unique:menus,menu_name"
        ]);

    $menu = new Menu;
    $menu->menu_name = $request->menu_name;
    $menu->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Menu successfully added!');
    return redirect()->route('menus.index');
}   

public function destroy($id)
{
    $menu = Menu::find($id);
    $menu->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'Menu was successfully deleted!');
    return redirect()->route('menus.index');
}
```

Comment: As said i have statically defined routes and created view pages for those routes

Comment: grammar fixed

tag routing added